# Prove that there exists an isomorphism between $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ and $\mathbb Q[\beta]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please, help me to understand this problem:

"Let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$, $\beta=\sqrt[3]2\left( \frac{-1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2} \right)$ roots of the polynomial $x^3-2$. Prove that there exists an isomorphism between $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ and $\mathbb Q[\beta]$".

Solution:

$p(x)=x^3-2$ is a polynomial irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. It follows that $<p(x)>$ is a maximal ideal.Consider the homomorphisms $F_1:\mathbb {Q}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb {Q}[\alpha];f(x) \mapsto f(\alpha)$ and $F_2:\mathbb {Q}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb {Q}[\beta];f(x) \mapsto f(\beta)$. The Homomorphism Theorem tells me that $\frac{\mathbb {Q}[x]}{<p(x)>}$ is a field and that $\mathbb {Q}[\alpha] \cong \frac{\mathbb {Q}[x]}{<p(x)>} \cong \mathbb {Q}[\beta]$.

Now, this is my question: since $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha] \cong \mathbb{Q}[\beta]$, then there exists a "copy" of $\mathbb {Q}[\alpha]$ inside $\mathbb{Q}[\beta]$. But $\{ a_0,a_1 \sqrt[3]{2},a_2(\sqrt[3]{2})^2 \}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and $\{b_0,b_1\left(\frac{-\sqrt[3]{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right),b_2\left(\frac{-\sqrt[3]{4}}{4}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right) \}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}[\beta]$. It should be possible to represent an elemente of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ in terms of the basis of $\mathbb{Q}[\beta]$, but I didn't manage to do it.

Comment: your polynomial needs to be $x^3-2$ not $x^3-1$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I commited a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider any finite dimensional vector space $V$ with $dim\ V=n$. Then $V\equiv \mathbb{R}^n$. Thus there exists a copy of $V$ inside $\mathbb{R}^n$, but that doesn't mean that every element of $V$ can be expressed in terms of the basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What is true is that any element of the "copy" of $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be expressed in terms of the basis of the latter. Thus the isomorphism only says that there is a set inside $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ which behaves exactly as $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, but $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not sitting inside $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.

Comment: Hello, Wanderer! Do you mean, for example, that $\sqrt[3]{2} \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, but $\sqrt[3]{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}[\beta]$?

Comment: @Walterr yes, something like that. Recall that while defining an isomorphism one just fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ and sends $\alpha$ to $\beta$.